Triangle bool topology fix for bevel workflow
Well as title says I have a trouble with understanding of topology in case like this one on the image:

After many attempts of solving this I came to:


But it gives my model a "stretches" in 3 directions after bevel or bevel + subd.
I have tried to fix it with weighted normals mod but the result is still far from perfect:

I am probably doing it wrong. Much appreciate any help or tips

You could try this topology instead:

If you need to make the bottom rounder, create this topology:

Result with a Subdivision Surface:


well this is not exactly what I am looking for, since I need to bevel this middle edge from the top vertex of triangle: link and when I am doing so, it gives me the same issue I described in post. But it looks better then what I have now link

I'm not sure what you mean, do you have an image of the real object?

not really :( I just want to make this corner more round. link

I've edited my answer, is it correct?

YES! Now I see that it was so obvious. Thank you for make it clear
